# How can I give 2 names for the same voice command in Dragon NaturallySpeaking?

Tags: dragon-naturally-speaking

How can I give 2 names for the same voice command in Dragon NaturallySpeaking? I.e., I want to be able to use two different names for the same voice command.

I know I can use one of these two solutions:

- use the [HeardWord function](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/159833/20338) to enable Dragon NaturallySpeaking to behave as if the specified word, word sequence, or voice command was received by the recognizer, which can be used to call another function.
- [use the '#Uses directive to incorporate a global set of constants and functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36701641/395857).

but I am curious to know whether there exist some more direct way to define two names for the same voice command.